# Correct arguments? Embed using variables?

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

Hi I'm very new to discord.py, I am creating a bot for my friends server as a test.

In the `commands` arguments, I want to pass three separate arguments, one is the author of the message, two is an amount of time (i.e '2 days') and the third is for text.

However, I want these arguments stored as variables to use later on in the embed.

So I have two questions;

1. Is that the correct way to pass the arguments?
2. How do I use a variable in the `value=` section of the Embeds fields?

Here is the code:

(fyi if you spot anything else I've done wrong please let me know, also assume you're explaining this to a toddler because I'm new and super dumb)

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Moderator')
async def slm(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, time: int = None, *, reason=None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
    loa = ctx.guild.get_role(848032714715561985)
    mod = ctx.guild.get_role(848032880709074944)
    await member.add_roles(loa)
    await member.remove_roles(mod)
    file = open("modRecord.csv", "a")
    file.write(str(ctx.author.id))
    file.close()
    await ctx.send("I have filed your Leave, take care, we look forward to your return!")
    modLogEmbed = discord.Embed(title='Leave Logs',
                                description="A member of Staff is going on leave! " + str(member), color=0x00ff00)
    modLogEmbed.add_field(name="Time",
                          value='time here', inline=False)
    modLogEmbed.add_field(name="Reason for Leave:",
                          value="Unreleased", inline=False)
    modLogEmbed.set_footer(text="LeaveManager Bot")
    modLogEmbed.set_author(name='Leave Manager')
    botLogChannel = client.get_channel(874959002172268685)
    await botLogChannel.send(embed=modLogEmbed)
```

Also I don't know how to get the code to layout properly on here, if someone can fix that I'd appreciate it.

Comment: This is not really the site where you ask people to improve your code (you should ask in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) however I can give you a couple of tips: look at f-strings (for string formatting) and context managers (for the `open` function), you should also use `case_snake` instead of `camelCase` for variable names since it's the convention (according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles))

Comment: Ah okay, thanks man, I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.6, you can format strings using f strings, i.e.:

```py
name = "Bob"
new_string = f"My name is {name}"
```

(Documentation can be found **[here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)**)

Which would display as `"My name is Bob"`. You can use this, but in your case, since it appears that you don't need to format it and only need to convert the variables to a string, you can do:

```py
modLogEmbed.add_field(name="Time:",value=str(time), inline=False)
modLogEmbed.add_field(name="Reason for Leave:",value=str(reason), inline=False)
```